# Log4j2: log level INFO but special markers with DEBUG

Tags: spring-boot, filter, log4j2

Hi I want to filter my logs in a special way:
I have a high frequented system. A lot of devices are connected and are sending messages all time. To log all is impossible.
Now I'm searching for a way to log all things are not depending on device messages and to log the other messages only of a special device.
I found, that I could mark these logs but I have no idea to combine both log types:

```
public someMethod (String serial){
   Marker sm = org.slf4j.MarkerFactory.getMarker(serial);
   log.info("A log message I want to find each time");
   log.debug(sm, "This log I want to filter out only for serial: "+ serial);
   ...
```

I'm working with spring boot and log4j.
I tried vaious filters, but without success.
Any one any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I found it by myself:
here the start of my log4j2.xml:

```
<Configuration monitorInterval="60">
   <filters>
      <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
      <MarkerFilter marker="serial" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
   </filters>
   ...
 <Appenders> ...
```